# Refactoring two node-accessing methods

Tags: c#

I cannot edit the `QueryPermissions` class because it is an external .dll that was given to me to use. Yes, I realize it's a bad practice to use an out variables, but I am pushing for a rewrite of that service.

As you can see below the two methods do the almost the EXACT same thing only one uses a `groupkey` and the other uses a `userkey` and then calls the appropriate method. For whatever reason I am drawing a blank on refactoring these methods.

```
public IEnumerable<Node> GetNodesForUser(int userKey, IEnumerable<OnlineReport> onlineReports)
{
    var nodes = new List<Node>();
    foreach (var onlineReport in onlineReports)
    {
        var parentNode = new Node {Text = onlineReport.Key, Value = onlineReport.Value};
        var webQueries = new List<WebQuery>();
        //Line that is different
        _QueryPermissions.GetQueriesForTaskAndUser(Int32.Parse(onlineReport.Value), userKey, ref webQueries, true);
        foreach (var childNode in webQueries.Select(webQuery => new Node(parentNode){Text = webQuery.QueryTitle, Value = webQuery.QueryKey.ToString()}))
        {
            parentNode.Children.Add(childNode);
        }
        nodes.Add(parentNode);
    }
    return nodes;
}

public IEnumerable<Node> GetNodesForGroup(int groupKey, IEnumerable<OnlineReport> onlineReports)
{
    var nodes = new List<Node>();
    foreach (var onlineReport in onlineReports)
    {
        var parentNode = new Node { Text = onlineReport.Key, Value = onlineReport.Value };
        var webQueries = new List<WebQuery>();
        //Line that is different
         _QueryPermissions.GetQueriesForTaskAndUserGroup(Int32.Parse(onlineReport.Value), groupKey, ref webQueries, true);
        foreach (var childNode in webQueries.Select(webQuery => new Node(parentNode) { Text = webQuery.QueryTitle, Value = webQuery.QueryKey.ToString() }))
        {
            parentNode.Children.Add(childNode);
        }
        nodes.Add(parentNode);
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The big difference between the functions is not the `userKey` vs. `groupKey` but rather than they have different queries embedded in them

```
_QueryPermissions.GetQueriesForTaskAndUser(Int32.Parse(onlineReport.Value), userKey, ref webQueries, true);
```

**vs.**

```
_QueryPermissions.GetQueriesForTaskAndUserGroup(Int32.Parse(onlineReport.Value), groupKey, ref webQueries, true);
```

It looks like these can be abstracted as

```
 delegate void NodeQueryDelegate(int reportValue, int key, ref List<WebQuery> webQueries, bool someBool);
```

so it should be possible to refactor thus

```
public IEnumerable<Node> GetNodesFromQuery(int key, IEnumerable<OnlineReport> onlineReports, NodeQueryDelegate query) {
    var nodes = new List<Node>();
    foreach (var onlineReport in onlineReports)  {
        var parentNode = new Node { Text = onlineReport.Key, Value = onlineReport.Value };
        var webQueries = new List<WebQuery>();
        //Line that is different
        query(Int32.Parse(onlineReport.Value), key, ref webQueries, true);
        foreach (var childNode in webQueries.Select(webQuery => new Node(parentNode) { Text = webQuery.QueryTitle, Value = webQuery.QueryKey.ToString() })) {
            parentNode.Children.Add(childNode);
        }
        nodes.Add(parentNode);
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

Getting the user nodes becomes

```
var userNodes = GetNodesFromQuery(userKey, onlineReports, _QueryPermissions.GetQueriesForTaskAndUser);
```

Getting the group node

```
var groupNodes = GetNodesFromQuery(groupKey, onlineReports, _QueryPermissions.GetQueriesForTaskAndUserGroup);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a delegate?

```
private delegate void Query(int value, int key, ref List<WebQuery>, bool b);

public void SomeCallingMethod()
{
  IEnumerable<OnlineReport> reports;
  // one way
  int myUserKey;
  Query q = _QueryPermissions.GetQueriesForTaskAndUser;
  var returnValue = GetNodesForUser(q, myUserKey, reports);
  //or the other
  int groupKey;
  q = _QueryPermissions.GetQueriesForTaskAndUserGroup;
  returnValue = GetNodesForUser(q, groupKey, reports);
}

public IEnumerable<Node> GetNodesForUser(Query query, int key, IEnumerable<OnlineReport> onlineReports)
{
  var nodes = new List<Node>();
  foreach (var onlineReport in onlineReports)
  {
    var parentNode = new Node { Text = onlineReport.Key, Value = onlineReport.Value };
    var webQueries = new List<WebQuery>();
    //Line that is different
    // _QueryPermissions.GetQueriesForTaskAndUser(Int32.Parse(onlineReport.Value), userKey, ref webQueries, true);
    query.Invoke(Int32.Parse(onlineReport.Value), key, ref webQueries, true);
    foreach (var childNode in webQueries.Select(webQuery => new Node(parentNode) { Text = webQuery.QueryTitle, Value = webQuery.QueryKey.ToString() }))
    {
      parentNode.Children.Add(childNode);
    }
    nodes.Add(parentNode);
  }
  return nodes;
}
```